# Does a different port number mean a different domain?

Tags: asp.net

I am running two ASP.NET applications simultaneously, on two different ports. Does this mean that they are running on different domains?

My applications are running on localhost:9059 and localhost:56567, to be precise.

Comment: They can be on different domains or the same, depend on your settings.

Comment: They can be different or same, I have added answer for explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost` is just available to you local machine for testing/debugging. If you want to access any application in Asp.net on other machine you will need machine name or IP or DNS with website name.

So on your local answer can be both yes & no.

But in general answer is **NO** for site having same name are treated as same domain in terms of cookie-sharing, single sign-on, certificates,bearer token or auth token etc.

Also in hosted web sites on internet are browsed on port 80 on browser machine for http sites & port 443 for https irrespective of local hosting port.

Comment: Regarding CORS and testing locally, apps on different ports are considered as different origins. And when enabling single route CORS via options, need to include the port number with the 'domain' as well. E.g: "origin: 'http://localhost:3000'".